# Virtual Kubelet: node selection on scale-out and scale-in

Tags: azure, kubernetes

We have a simple 3-node Kubernetes cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). A lot of the time that's more than sufficient infrastructure-wise, but occasionally we need to be able scale out for a couple hours to 50 instances of a service then scale back again.

Combining AKS with Azure Container Instances (ACI) via the Virtual Kubelet seems like an ideal solution for this scenario.

From a cost management perspective, we'd prefer stuff running on *our* VMs if there's available capacity. We're already paying for them, so there's no point paying for ACI instances too.

**Question 1**

If we scale out via the Virtual Kubelet using ACI, how does Kubernetes choose which pods to scale *back* later on? Is its approach consistent with our cost management requirement - i.e. "genuine" nodes are preferred - or could it be made to be consistent?

**Question 2**

Scenario: we run two apps - "App1" and "App2" - in Kubernetes. *App1* is the one that causes the need to scale out to 50 instances via ACI; *App2* is running on the "genuine" nodes.

Say we then use Helm to update *App2*. When it restarts, I'm guessing Kubernetes *could* place it on an ACI instance since we're at scale at that point.

Later, the need for the 50 instances of *App1* goes away and we scale back again.

*App2* would still be running on ACI instances when we'd prefer them to be back on genuine nodes at this point.

Would Kubernetes manage this according to our cost managemet requirements, or is some extra shepherding required?

Comment: It looks like traits and tolerances will play a role in scaling *out* (i.e. `PreferNoSchedule`), but still not clear on scaling *in*.

Comment: do you know when this is supposed to happen? this looks like a good fir for cronjob resource in that case

Comment: Unfortunately not - it's not a time-based thing but a queue-based thing.

Comment: yeah, i dont think you can change your placement constrains on scale (i mean, you have to change it before scaling takes place)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question - a `PreferNoSchedule` taint on the Virtual Kubelet will deter pods from being scheduled on the more expensive resources when scaling *up*, but the scheduler isn't involved in scaling *down*.

The "victim" is chosen as a result of the following tests:

1. Pod unassigned vs assigned
2. Pod status
3. Pod readiness
4. Recentness of pod readiness
5. Pod restart counts
6. Pod creation time

See:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/886e04f1fffbb04faf8a9f9ee141143b2684ae68/pkg/controller/controller_utils.go#L726

In short, there's no real way of controlling victims in a scale-down scenario without resorting to hacky approaches and race conditions.

In the end, we've gone a different path: having two different deployments of the same application and a taint on the Virtual Kubelet:

1. One deployment that doesn't have a tolerance for the Virtual Kubelet taint - min replicas of 1 and also a max replicas of 5.
2. Another deployment that has a tolerance for the Virtual Kubelet taint and also a nodeSelector for it. Default replica count is 0 but we can obviously scale that when required.

Outside of that, we have our own microservice running that monitors an Azure Service Bus queue length and makes scaling decisions for the two deployments.

Not quite as elegant as we wished, but does give us complete control over what lives where in our cluster.

Hope this helps somebody!